# A mother has two children. What is the probability, given this information that both are girls?

Tags: probability

**The Problem**

You know that your new neighbors have two children. One day you
see the mother taking a walk with a girl. What is the probability that the other child is also a girl?

**a)** Given that the mother chooses the younger child with probability $p$.

**b)** Given that if the children are of different genders, the mother chooses the girl with probability $p$.

**My solution**

First of all assume that the mother walks only with her children.

Lets mark the observed girl and order them by age, then sample space is
$S=\{b^*b,bb^*,b^*g,bg^*,g^*b,gb^*,g^*g,gg^*\}$. We are interested of the case in which both are girls $GG=\{g^*g,gg^*\}$

**a)** Let $Y=\{\text{The mother chooses to walk with the younger child}\}$,
then we have
$$
P(GG)=P(GG|Y)P(Y)+P(GG|Y^c)P(Y^c)=\\
=\frac{p/4}{p}p+\frac{(1-p)/4}{1-p}(1-p)=1/2
$$
(Using Law of Total Probability and def. of conditional prob.)

**b)** My attempt is to let $G^*=\{\text{The mother chooses to walk with a girl}\}$, $B^*=\{\text{The mother chooses to walk with a boy}\}$ and $D=\{\text{children has different gender}\}$, then we have
$$
P(G^*|D)=p,
$$
$$
P(B^*|D)=1-p.
$$
But i guess I'm interested in $GG=G^*\cap D^c$.

Comment: How did you get $\frac{p / 4}{p} p + \frac{(1 - p) / 2)}{1 - p}(1 - p) = \frac{1}{2}$? Also, where did account for observation "mother walks with a girl" (in the first case)?

Comment: I used conditional probability and law of total prob. that $P(GG)=P(GG \cap Y)+(GG \cap Y^c)=P(gg^*)+P(g^*g)=p/4+(1-p)/4$. Then I think each outcome in the two seperate cases has the same probability. Yes, you found one error, it should be $1/4$

Comment: But you want to find probability of both children to be a girl **given** you saw a girl. For example, assume $p = 1$ - mother always walks with the younger child. What is then the probability of the other to be a girl too?

Comment: Given that I saw one girl, Im down to the cases $\{bg^*,g^*b,g^*g,gg^*\}$, if $p=1$, then i would know that $\{bg^*,gg^*\}$ happened. then a uniform pick of two?

Comment: Yes, so it will be $\frac{1}{2}$, but your calculations give $\frac{1}{4}$ - that's because you didn't condition on seeing a girl.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Then Im Interested to assign probabilities to $P(GG|G^*)=P(GG|G^*\cap Y)P(Y|G^*)+P(GG|G^*\cap Y^c)P(Y^c|G^*)$?

Comment: Assuming $G*$ is "you saw a girl" - yes, it's one of ways to get it correctly.

Comment: Okey, thanks now I was able assign probabilities to $P(GG|G^*)=P(GG|G^*\cap Y)P(G^*|Y)+P(GG|G^*\cap Y^c)P(G^*|Y^c)$, and see why its independent of $p$.

Comment: Any tips or directions for b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $b$, you are interested in $P(D^c | G^*)$, not in $P(D^c \cap G^*)$ - we already know that $G^*$ happened. It's standard applying of Bayes rule: $P(D^c | G^*) = \frac{P(G^* | D^c) \cdot P(D^c)}{P(G^*)}$.

For numerator, $P(G^* | D^c) = \frac{1}{2}$ (if children have the same gender, then $G^*$ is equal to both of them been girls) and $P(D^c) = \frac{1}{2}$, thus numerator is $\frac{1}{4}$.

For denominator lets use law of total probability (with events $gg$, $gb$ and $bb$ denoting two girls, boy and girl and two boys): $P(G^*) = P(G^* | gg) \cdot P(gg) + P(G^* | gb) \cdot P(gb) + P(G^* | bb) \cdot P(bb) = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4} + p \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 0 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1 + 2p}{4}$.

So the final answer is $\frac{1}{1 + 2p}$. For sanity check, we can check that if $p = 0$ this probability is $1$ (only mothers with two girls will walk with a girl), and if $p = 1$ then probability if $\frac{1}{3}$ (all mothers with at least one girl will walk with a girl, and among them $\frac{1}{3}$ has two girls).